# Apache Camel modifies JSON when CONTENT_TYPE is application/json

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, content-type

I'm building my REST-API with Apache Camel and I use "bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)" for my restConfiguration with jetty. In one of my Processors I set the "body" of the "out" object with a String that actually is a JSON object. When I set the Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE to "text/plain" the response comes in as expected and can directly be parsed to a JSON object.

```
{"mockBasicData":"123"}
```

But when I set the Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE to "application/json" or if I don't set it at all, Camel manipulates the body and escapes it, like it wouldn't already be a JSON object.

```
{\"mockBasicData\":\"123\"}
```

Is there a way to avoid that auto-escaping in Camel, as I need the CONTENT_TYPE to be "application/json"?

Comment: have you tried using RestBindingMode.Auto ?

Comment: Yes, doesn‘t help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding "bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)" directly to the route (not to rest()!) solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

The typical use of the RestBinding is to specify the marshalling **from POJO** to json or xml. If I understand correctly what you said, you are converting a json string body to json, right ?
If so, have you tried to set the body of the out object with the JSON **Object** it-self ?

Please also note the following:

> From Camel 2.16.3 onwards the binding from POJO to JSon/JAXB will only
>   happen if the content-type header includes json or xml. This allows
>   you to specify a custom content-type if the message body should not
>   attempt to be marshalled using the binding. This is useful if, for
>   example, the message body is a custom binary payload.

Comment: Yes, adding the JSON object itself still results in Camel adding escape characters.